# How to pass image using Image Id in intent to different activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to learn to create a meme generator app. First I had a problem with my app crashing when I clicked on the images in the grid view as the images were too big. I was advised to use image id to pass the image to the second activity. I (thought, I) changed the code accordingly. Now when clicked on the image, I can see the next activity with enter top and bottom text options but still image does not appear. I know the problem is the way I am passing image id but don't know what. I hope you can give me specific code as I am very new to programming.

I know using uri also is an option but being a beginner I am not sure how I would execute that here. If you think it is a better (in terms of speed of the app and memory usage / easier to learn and execute), you would be kind enough to help me out with the code too, would be appreciated.

Thank You in advance!

Here is my code:

Main Activity.java

```
package com.javatechig.gridviewexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                //Create intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());

                //Start details activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prepare some dummy data for gridview
     */
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, R.array.image_ids));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }
}
```

DetailsActivity.java

```
package com.javatechig.gridviewexample;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        //imageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
        Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("id");

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

ImageItem.java

```
package com.javatechig.gridviewexample;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class ImageItem {
    private Bitmap image;
    private int id;

    public ImageItem(Bitmap image, int id) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

GridViewAdapter.java

```
package com.javatechig.gridviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }


        ImageItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're just passing the id field through the intent and you're not storing the object anywhere to get a reference to it.

Comment: @chRyNaN : I would like to try your suggestion. Only problem is I am just a beginner in programming. Anyway you can give me some lines of code and get me started? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. To start, you are obtaining your images from the resources but when you create a new ImageItem and add it to the ArrayList you are not passing in the individual resource ID. Here is the relevant part of your getData() method:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
    //Here you are putting in the generic R.array.image_ids
    //Instead you should put in the images specific id: imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
    imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, R.array.image_ids));
}
```

Next, you are incorrectly passing and retrieving data between Activities. Here's your relevant code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", item.getId()); //You are putting in an int extra

...

//You are attempting to retrieve a Parcelable extra even though you only
//passed in an int
Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("id");
```

And finally, I want to make it clear that you are not storing these ImageItems anywhere, so, you wouldn't be able to retrieve the correct ImageItem with the ID to get the image.

**So, what's the solution?**

As you may know Bitmaps can be quite large and passing them between Activities isn't the best approach as there can be many issues in doing so. One way of getting around this is storing them in a File and retrieving that same File in the other Activity. Fortunately, all of the Bitmaps you need are already stored in your resources, so, you can just get them from there.

First, fix your getData() method:

```
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)));
        }
    }finally{
        imgs.recycle(); //When done recycle your TypedArray
    }
    return imageItems;
}
```

Then, your onCreate() method in DetailsActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
    if(id != -1){
        //We have the resource ID so we can retreive the item
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }else{
        //We don't have the resource ID so show default View or perform task
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You have been a great help. You went out of you way to write such a detailed answer for me. I am thankful.

Comment: @Pinkesh S , I'm glad it helped. If it solved your problem make sure to accept the answer and consider an up vote.

Comment: Just accepted the answer. Do not have enough reputation yet to +1 yet. But well on my way there with the help from people like you. Will sure come back to +1 once eligible. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

item.getId() is the unique ID in memory , not the image's resource ID, you should use resource ID.
the simple way ,  you can set resource ID as imageItems ID in setgetData().

Comment: Hey, thank you for your prompt reply. I tried but cant find any guidance around how i can do what you suggested here. Just so you know, I am just a beginner in programming. Is it possible for you to give me some more help and provide me code? Thanks in advance.